# Sort list according to order of larger list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an ordered list:

```py
ordering = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
```

and a smaller unordered list I want to sort according to this list:

```py
unordered = ["blue", "orange", "red"]
```

to give the result:

```py
["red", "blue", "orange"]
```

This seems like the sort of question that would have already been asked, but I have been through all the similarly worded questions I can find and none of them solve this case.

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to do this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I couldn't think how to do it. I figured I would need some kind of for loop to loop over the list and then look at where the item appears in the larger list, and then store that value in another list, but this seemed too complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort()` has an argument that lets you write a sorting function. You can use this sorting function as following:

```py
unordered.sort(key=lambda x: ordering.index(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution:

```py
ordering = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
unordered = ["blue", "orange", "red"]

[x for x in ordering if x in unordered]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ordering = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
unordered = ["blue", "orange", "red"]
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(ordering)}
unordered.sort(key=d.get)
    
print(unordered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your colors a numerical value and sort your unordered list using them

```
ordering = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]

ordering_dict = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(ordering)}
unordered = ["blue", "orange", "red"]

sorted_list = sorted(unordered, key=lambda x: ordering_dict[x])
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(ordering))` --> `for i,key in enumerate(ordering): ordering_dict[key] = i`

Answer (score -2):

I think you can possibly make another (third) list, search for items in the 2nd list in the order of the 1st, and then removing every item on the 2nd list and replace with the items from the 3rd one

Comment: A good answer should include code that shows how your method generates the expected output